# Error after installation Open Fire XMPP

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I had installed open fire in windows 7 and it returns below error!! still when I launch admin and process further then I am unable to install plugins also

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
```

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Openfire\bin..\logs\all.log (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:289)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:167)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:163)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:256)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:220)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:150)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:163)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:425)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseRoot(DOMConfigurator.java:394)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:829)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:712)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:618)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:470)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.(LogManager.java:122)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:277)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:288)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.XMPPServer.(XMPPServer.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.start(ServerStarter.java:105)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.main(ServerStarter.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:65)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:101)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:26)
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Openfire\bin..\logs\debug.log (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:289)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:167)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:163)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:256)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:220)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:150)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:163)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:425)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseRoot(DOMConfigurator.java:394)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:829)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:712)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:618)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:470)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.(LogManager.java:122)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:277)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:288)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.XMPPServer.(XMPPServer.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.start(ServerStarter.java:105)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.main(ServerStarter.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:65)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:101)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:26)
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Openfire\bin..\logs\info.log (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:289)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:167)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:163)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:256)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:220)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:150)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:163)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:425)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseRoot(DOMConfigurator.java:394)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:829)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:712)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:618)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:470)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.(LogManager.java:122)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:277)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:288)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.XMPPServer.(XMPPServer.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.start(ServerStarter.java:105)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.main(ServerStarter.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:65)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:101)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:26)
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Openfire\bin..\logs\warn.log (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:289)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:167)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:163)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:256)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:220)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:150)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:163)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:425)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseRoot(DOMConfigurator.java:394)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:829)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:712)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:618)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:470)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.(LogManager.java:122)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:277)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:288)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.XMPPServer.(XMPPServer.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.start(ServerStarter.java:105)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.main(ServerStarter.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:65)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:101)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:26)
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Openfire\bin..\logs\error.log (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:289)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:167)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:163)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:256)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:220)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:150)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:163)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:425)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseRoot(DOMConfigurator.java:394)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:829)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:712)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:618)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:470)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.(LogManager.java:122)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:277)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:288)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.XMPPServer.(XMPPServer.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.start(ServerStarter.java:105)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.starter.ServerStarter.main(ServerStarter.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:65)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:101)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:26)
Openfire 4.0.3 [Oct 5, 2016 11:27:49 PM]
Admin console listening at http://mohit-pc:9090

[error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDiPU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you don't have grants to write in selected folder.

Just install Openfire in another directory such like

```
C:\Openfire

C:\MyPrograms\Openfire
```

and avoid  `C:\Program Files\`